# (Libnm) Specifying password when connecting to wifi from C program

Tags: c, wifi, glib

I have found out how to connect to a wifi-network from a C program using the following function:

https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/NMClient.html#nm-client-activate-connection-async

Now, my question is; what if the network requires a password? The function has no such argument.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?  I am trying to figure out the same thing!

Comment: @CMDoolittle I think I just ended up running a system command: "nmcli device wifi connect <network-id> password <password>"

Answer (score 2):

you need generate a `NMSettingWirelessSecurity` with password to connection. take a look at nmcli [root/src/nmcli/devices.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/src/nmcli/devices.c#n3950) which use libnm

generate `NMSettingWirelessSecurity`

```
s_wsec = nm_connection_get_setting_wireless_security(connection);
```

add setting

```
nm_connection_add_setting(connection, NM_SETTING(s_wsec));
```

set password `NMSettingWirelessSecurity`

```
if (ap_wpa_flags == NM_802_11_AP_SEC_NONE && ap_rsn_flags == NM_802_11_AP_SEC_NONE) {
    /* WEP */
    nm_setting_wireless_security_set_wep_key(s_wsec, 0, password);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(s_wsec),
                    NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_SECURITY_WEP_KEY_TYPE,
                    wep_passphrase ? NM_WEP_KEY_TYPE_PASSPHRASE : NM_WEP_KEY_TYPE_KEY,
                    NULL);
} else if ((ap_wpa_flags & NM_802_11_AP_SEC_KEY_MGMT_PSK)
            || (ap_rsn_flags & NM_802_11_AP_SEC_KEY_MGMT_PSK)
            || (ap_rsn_flags & NM_802_11_AP_SEC_KEY_MGMT_SAE)) {
    /* WPA PSK */
    g_object_set(s_wsec, NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_SECURITY_PSK, password, NULL);
}
```

activate

```
nm_client_add_and_activate_connection_async(nmc->client,
                                                    connection,
                                                    info->device,
                                                    info->specific_object,
                                                    NULL,
                                                    add_and_activate_cb,
                                                    info);
```